# Zend_Form : render properly an image element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm using the Zend_Form_Element_Image on my Zend Form.
This outputs :

```
<input id="media_img" type="image" src="/img/bigbtn-add.png" name="media_img">
```

What do think about that type="image" writing ?
Do you prefer the "img" tag instead ?

If yes, someone stacked this solution to render an "img" element : [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137873/adding-img-tag-in-zend-form#answer-6141891)

Is it the only way to render a classic "img" tag on Zend 1.12 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` with type `image` is actually a submit button that uses an image. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

It's not the same as an `img` tag.

So depends on what you want to render.

In general, I think it's a bit easier to work with `Zend_Form_Decorator_View_Script` since you  have better control of your HTML. See here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript